# javaScript - Find the sum of all divisors of a given integer

Tags: javascript, math

i'm doing some coding exercises and i'm not being able to solve this one.

Find the sum of all divisors of a given integer.
For n = 12, the  input should be
sumOfDivisors(n) = 28.

example: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 12 = 28.

Constraints:
1 ≤ n ≤ 15.

how can i solve this exercise? i'm not being able to.

```
function(n){
    var arr = [],
        finalSum;

    if(n <= 1 || n => 16){
       return false ;   
   }
   for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
       var tmp= n/2;
       arr.push(tmp)    
       // i need to keep on dividing n but i can't get the way of how to
   }
  return finalSum;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is another way to do it:

```js
var divisors = n=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].slice(1)
   .reduce((s, a)=>s+(!(n % a) && a), 0);

console.log(divisors(12));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32n5jdnb/141/

Explaining:

- `n=>`                   this is an arrow function, the equivalent to function(n) {. You don't need the () if there's only one parameter.
- `Array(n+1)`              creates an empty array of n+1 elements
- `.keys()`                 gets the keys of the empty array (the indexes i.e. 0, 1, 2) so this is a way to create a numeric sequence
- `[...Array(n+1)].keys()]` uses the spread (...) operator to transform the iterator in another array so creating an array with the numeric sequence
- `.slice(1)`              removes the first element thus creating a sequence starting with 1. Remember the n+1 ?
- `.reduce()`              is a method that iterates though each element and calculates a value in order to reduce the array to one value. It receives as parameter a callback function to calculate the value and the initial value of the calculation
- `(s, a)=>`               is the callback function for reduce. It's an arrow function equivalent to function(s, a) {
- `s+(!(n % a) && a)`    is the calculation of the value.
- `s+`                     s (for sum) or the last value calculated +
- `!(n % a)`            this returns true only for the elements that have a 0 as modular value.
- `(!(n % a) && a)`      is a js 'trick'. The case is that boolean expressions in javascript don't return true or false. They return a 'truthy' or 'falsy' value which is then converted to boolean. So the actual returned value is the right value for && (considering both have to be truthy) and the first thuthy value found for || (considering only one need to be truthy). So this basically means: if `a` is a modular value (i.e. != 0) return `a` to add to the sum, else return 0.
- `, 0`                    is the initial value for the reduce calculation.

Reduce documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

**Edit**

Answering to Tristan Forward:

```js
var divisorsList = [];
var divisors = (n)=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].slice(1)
       .reduce((s, a)=>{
          var divisor = !(n % a) && a;
          if (divisor) divisorsList.push(divisor);
          return s+divisor;
       }, 0);
    

console.log('Result:', divisors(12));
console.log('Divisors:', divisorsList);
```

Comment: Any idea how to return a list of divisors from this function versus adding them?

Comment: @TristanForward included an example to answer you.

Comment: just another example to find divisors with no use of reduce:

`const divisors = (n) => [...Array(n + 1).keys()].slice(1).filter((i) => n % i === 0);`

Answer (score 5):

You have to check if specified number is or not a divisor of given integer. You can use modulo `%` - if there's no rest, specified number is the divisor of the given integer - add it to the sum.

```js
function sumDivisors(num){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    if (!(num % i)) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  console.log(sum);
}

sumDivisors(6);
sumDivisors(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with better algorithm performance (O(sqrt(largest prime factor of n)))

```
divisors = n => {
  sum = 1
  for (i = 2; n > 1; i++) {
    i * i > n ? i = n : 0
    b = 0
    while (n % i < 1) {
      c = sum * i
      sum += c - b
      b = c
      n /= i
    }
  }
  return sum
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

since `n / i` is also a devisor this can be done more efficiently.

```
function sumDivisors(num) {
    let sum = 1;
    
    for (let i = 2; i < num / i; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            sum += i + num / i;
        }
    }

    const sqrt = Math.sqrt(num);
    return num + (num % sqrt === 0 ? sum + sqrt : sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function countDivisors(n){
 let counter = 1;
 for(let i=1; i <= n/2; i++){
  n % i === 0 ? counter++ : null;
 }
 return counter
}
```

in this case, we consider our counter as starting with 1 since by default all numbers are divisible by 1. Then we half the number since numbers that can be able to divide n are less or equal to half its value